# Does "East" mean "Middle east" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://youtu.be/EctE3dEAwEY?t=5m20s

> Dubai now has the world's busiest airport for international passenger traffic, confirming its position as a gateway to **the East.**

Does "East" in this context mean "Middle East?"
Or does it mean East Asia? What does "the East" here refer to?

Comment: *The East* in that context encompasses all of the above - and it's very likely that the author intended it to.

Comment: It's anything that is in the West or West [typically, Europe and the Americas].

Comment: @Lambie The other two answers say it's either "the East Asia" or "both the East and the Middle East." I'm still not sure... How can "the East" be "the Western countries" as you said?

Comment: Oops, anything that is ***not*** in the West. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The East" is deliberately vague, the author intends it to include most of Asia including the Far East, and the Middle East.  [wiktionary sense 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/East)

By being vague the advert can be applicable to more people.